# Windows update error 0x800703ee

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, windows-10-upgrade, windows-10-v1803

**Windows update cannot install the Windows 10 upgrade to version 1903, I tried upgrading manually through the Microsoft upgrade assistant and the same error happens, with the error message saying it "couldn't prove it had enough space to install windows" (%) (>25Go disk space available)**.

Indeed, my disk configuration is a bit weird, having had a lot of problems when switching Windows to the HDD to let my Ubuntu partition on the SSD. Here are the details of my disk partitions :[image]

Current windows version is 1803, build 17134.1006. Any idea what could be going wrong and how to fix it ? Search engines give me no help for this one.

It might not be related, but I noticed a very high disk usage recently, 100% almost all the time.

Thanks for helping

*(%) : Rough translation due to my Windows 10 version being in french*

EDIT : I freed up >35Gigs and the error is still the same. I'm getting pretty confident this is not a problem related to disk space.

Answer (score 2):

Your disk configuration is more than a bit weird, on these points:

- You have allocated all of Disk 1 to EFI partitions.
  Why allocate 118 GB to an EFI partition, when its size is at most 500 MB?
- Disk C is relatively small for Windows 10 and the 17 GB that are free might not be
  enough for the upgrade.
- I do not understand what purpose is served by the 109.32 GB partition
  (this might affect the rest of my answer below).

My advice would be:

- Reduce other partition(s) on Disk 0 to:

  - Add a few dozens of GB to C
  - Leave at least 500 MB as unallocated space for a new EFI partition
- Upgrade Windows 10 to version 1903
- If the above unallocated space is now used for a new EFI partition,
  you may now reformat Disk 1 and use it for data.

Before starting, I recommend taking an image backup of the entire Disk 0.
A product I recommend is
[AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.aomeitech.com/aomei-backupper.html),
and for good measures create also its boot media and try it in order to ensure
that it can see the backup device, just in case.

Comment: The 109.32 partition is my ubuntu /home partition. The Disk1 Partition1 of 118Go is Ubuntu partition, recognized as EFI because it has the bootable flag. I only use Disk1 Partition0 for booting though (it has Grub). Also, how do you want me to add "A few dozen GB to C:" ? Change my SSD ?

Comment: If you are sure that you only use Disk1 Partition0, then you can reformat the 118 GB Disk1 Partition1 as E, move data to E from D, reduce D creating space between it and C, boot Ubuntu and move C up to be before that space, boot Windows and resize C to include the space but leaving about 1 GB unallocated, finally upgrade Windows. Partition operations are risky, as the smallest error can destroy the disk, so take excellent backups of entire Disk 0 and Disk1 Partition0. This needs lots of external disk space and will be slow.

Comment: This sounds 1) risky and 2) time consuming, while probably not helping with the issue because I believe it is not a disk space problem, and if it is, why not suggest just to free up some disk space from the Windows partition ? Thanks for the detailed steps to improve the layout, will definitely do when I find some time and space to backup my disks

Comment: Upgrading Windows might destroy your dual boot that you will need to restore.

Comment: True. Thanks for the warning.

Comment: Also @harrymc, I use Disk1Partition1 ! It's my Ubuntu system !!

Comment: Why is Disk1Partition1 marked as EFI? (Unless Windows doesn't really understand Ubuntu.) Perhaps the real solution will be to upgrade Disk0.

Comment: No real reason, I must have messed up something when playing with my partitions earlier this year